# how to bring part of a layer to the top layer?

Tags: gimp, layers

I want to bring the point of the crown in front of the heart while leaving the rest behind.

[image]

Comment: As you mention layers, can we assume that you already have the crown and the heart on a layer of their own, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the crown and the heart as separate layers, duplicate the crown, but the copy on top, and erase most of it except where you want it to be above the heart.

If it's a single image, no way without redrawing things on a layer above. This said, these are straight lines, so it's not difficult:

- Create a path (red line)
- Sample the color of the crown
- Add a new layer
- `Select>From path` and bucket-fill the selection
- Set the FG color back to black, remove the selection, and `Edit>Stroke path`, in `Line` mode, with a width of 1 px
- With the eraser tool erase the two black segments at the bottom

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Comment: thank you, its been years since I used this program and I jumped in to start designing a tattoo

Comment: If the answer is OK, then "accept" it to tell others that this question has an accepted answer.